# multi layered python line interpreter using Cmd module

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface

I am trying to create a section of python code using the Cmd module to take the user's input and compute whatever needs to be done.

I've figured out how to manipulate and use the first word, which would be considered `input[0]`,

But how would I go about getting an input, such as `print hi`, and get the code to `print hi`?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use python's eval function. [Python Eval](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#:%7E:text=Python%27s%20eval()%20allows%20you,or%20a%20compiled%20code%20object.)

The gist of this function is: It evaluates a string ( which should be a correct python code )

```py
x = "print(hi)"
eval(x)
```

Output:

```
Hi
```

One more suggestion: Use the arg parser library of python for your command line arguments [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)